# How do I get the SpecFlow Scenario to be reported when the test runs?

Tags: nunit, specflow

I've managed to tune the output from my SpecFlow tests so that it reads nicely, with just the steps reported plus failures.  But it's still pretty unreadable without the Feature and Scenario names also being reported.

Looking at the generated code, it appears that the Feature and Scenario names are encoded as NUnit DescriptionAttributes.

Can I configure SpecFlow or NUnit to also report these to stdout, so I get a nicely flowing "story-like" output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you define an extra method in your step definition class as follows then NUnit will report the feature and scenario text.

```
[BeforeScenario]
public void OutputScenario()
{
  Console.WriteLine("Feature: " + FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo.Title);
  Console.WriteLine(FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo.Description);
  Console.WriteLine("\r\nScenario: " + ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Title);
}
```

I hope this helps.